# Como comprobar una condición cada cierto tiempo

Tags: java, android

Necesito que por favor me ayuden con un código para que la aplicación me verifique cada segundo sí se cumple con la siguiente condición que se encuentra dentro del método `startAlert();` :

Código :

```
package jaxper.comparacion;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {


    public  String getHora(String strFormato) {

        Calendar objCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(strFormato);

        String strHora = simpleDateFormat.format(objCalendar.getTime());
        return strHora;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        startAlert();

    }   public void startAlert() {


        String hora_sistema = getHora("HH:mm"); //hora sistema
        String mihora = "23:57"; //hora establecida

        int timeInSec = 5;

        if ( mihora.equals(hora_sistema )){


            Toast.makeText(this, " hola,despierta ",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


        }else {Toast.makeText(this, "aún no es la hora ",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar un [TimerTask](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TimerTask.html):

```
 Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

        startAlert(); //Proceso que se llama cada segundo.

        }

    },0,1000);//Cada segundo.
```

o un [Handler](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) que en este caso seria lo adecuado ya que estas mostrando un `Toast`:

```
   final Handler handler = new Handler();
    final Runnable r = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {

            startAlert();  //Proceso que se llama cada segundo.

            handler.postDelayed(this, 1000); //Cada segundo.
        }
    };

    handler.postDelayed(r, 1000);//Cada segundo.
```

---

Puedes llamar la ejecución de tu método `startAlert();` cada segundo dentro de `onCreate()` Este es un ejemplo:

```
  @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        final Runnable r = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {

                startAlert();  //Proceso que se llama cada segundo.

                handler.postDelayed(this, 1000); //Cada segundo.
            }
        };

        handler.postDelayed(r, 1000);//Cada segundo.



    }
```

Comment: Por favor me puedes indicar en que parte introduzco este código es que soy muy nuevo en esto,gracias.

Comment: Ya Alexader, actualicé la respuesta.

Comment: muchas gracias.

Comment: Excelente., un placer @Alexander